# C Split Char Array into an Array of Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

how do i convert

```
char* string = "test test test test";
```

into

```
char* array = ["test","test","test","test"];
```

if the length of the array is unknown?

Ty guys

Comment: Dynamic allocation and *re*allocation using `malloc` and `realloc`?

Comment: I would be shocked if `[c] split a string` as a search criteria on this site didn't proffer something useful.

Comment: `char* array = ["test","test","test","test"];` --> `char* array[] = {"test","test","test","test", NULL};`

Comment: This is not an array of arrays. A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to modify the memory, then you can do this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_next_start(char *str, char delim, int terminate) {
    char *p;
    p = strchr(str, delim);
    if (p != NULL) {
        if (terminate) {
            /* only nul-terminate the string on the second pass */
            *p = '\0';
        }
        p += 1;
    }
    return p;
}

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "test test test test";
    char **string_list;
    char *p;
    size_t i;

    /* count the elements... */
    i = 0;
    for (p = string; p != NULL; p = get_next_start(p, ' ', 0)) {
        i += 1;
    }
    printf("items: %zd\n", i);

    /* get some memory for the table */
    string_list = malloc(sizeof(string_list) * (i + 1));

    /* populate the table */
    i = 0;
    for (p = string; p != NULL; p = get_next_start(p, ' ', 1)) {
        string_list[i] = p; /* store the next item... */
        i += 1;
    }
    string_list[i] = NULL; /* terminate the list with NULL */

    /* print the table */
    for (i = 0; string_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%3zd: [%s]\n", i, string_list[i]);
    }

    /* free the memory */
    free(string_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the declaration of `string`...

- `char string[] = "test test test test"` places the data on the stack
- `char *string = "test test test test"` places the data in read-only memory

---

If you're not allowed to modify the memory, and want a single pass, then you can use `strndup()` to duplicate the strings, and `realloc()` to allocate and resize the table.